# How to enable autocomplete for type annotations for Rust variables in VS Code using rust-analyzer?

Tags: visual-studio-code, rust, autocomplete, rust-analyzer

When working with Rust in VS Code, there's an add-on/extension called [`rust-analyzer`](https://rust-analyzer.github.io/) that you can install via the [Marketplace](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rust-lang.rust-analyzer).

I remember watching a tutorial on Rust (don't have the link) and the person teaching had this feature where he'd type something to the effect of:

```rust
fn test(hello:
```

And VS Code would automatically auto complete it to something like:

```rust
fn test(hello: &str,
```

This was really neat and would go a long way especially when working with more complex types. Would anyone happen to know how to enable this, or if I'd need to install another extension to get it? I can't find the option on the extension's settings page.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Autocomplete hinting is an out-of-the-box feature of `rust-analyzer` that needs no manual config.

It's easy to activate/trigger the hinting.

Supposing you have already defined a first function `fn test1(s: &str) {/*...*/}` , then **when you are defining a second function** `fn test2(s`, you will see the hinting hovering over the code.
[image]

Comment: This had me scratching my head because I tried uninstalling and reinstalling the extension but after looking into it; it seemed the problem went beyond the extension. I traced the problem to a VS Code update that seemed to install duplicate files/folders in my config folder. So I uninstalled VS Code, deleted all config files and reinstalled VS Code and all extensions. Everything is now working as expected. Thanks for leading me in the right direction.